# Django Rest - Update not saving

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two `Model`, `Partner` and `PartnerAddress`, `Partner hasOne PartnerAddress`. I trying to update this `Related` field, However the field `Partner Address` is not save after update.

**`My ModelViewset`**

```
class PartnerViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Partner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PartnerSerialzer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # instance = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        # instance.name

        partner_address = request.data.get('partner_address')
        try:
            instance = Partner.objects.get(
                partner_address=partner_address['id'])
        except Partner.DoesNotExist:
            instance = None
        instance.house_no = request.data['partner_address']['house_no']
        instance.save()

        serializer = PartnerSerialzer(
            instance, data=request.data, partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Sorry I'm still new to Django. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks :)

Comment: can you copy paste  the traceback, and your serializer class.

Comment: @neferpitou u mean `HttpResponse(serializer.data)`?

Comment: If it is not saving there must be some errors. So paste those and your serializer. For errors you can check `serializer.errors`

Comment: @neferpitou i  tried `return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)` but nothing `error` shown.

Comment: @neferpitou sorry, but how can i `trace request` from `frontend`? i tried `instance.house_no = request.data.get('house_no')    return HttpResponse(instance.house_no)` but got `None`

Comment: `if serializer.is_valid():` your serializer save method `else:` print(serializer.errors)

Comment: @neferpitou still, i got no `error` :(

Comment: @neferpitou i updated my question, pls give alook..

Comment: hi, do you use request PATCH method or PUT ?

Comment: @monio thanks for ur comment. However, i found my answer. anyway thanks...

Comment: @latenight how could u solve this ?
I'm in the same problem it's weird problem!

Comment: @Fathy sorry i can't recall how i fixed this problem, its been long time